# Resource for finding what proteins bind?

Tags: proteins, database

I have two lists of proteins (including phosphorylated forms). I want to determine which members of each list act on which members of the other list. **What online resources exist for finding out what a given protein binds or otherwise interacts with?**

I am aware of [Uniprot](http://www.uniprot.org/) and [Phosphosite](http://www.phosphosite.org/homeAction.do) which have proved useful but I am wondering if there are others that I am not aware of.

Again: the question I am trying to answer is "which proteins from list A interact with proteins from list B and vice-versa?"

Comment: "the question I am trying to answer is 'which proteins from list A interact with proteins from list B and vice-versa?'" You and every biophysicist on the planet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the NAR database site and look for protein domain databases. You have multiple options. [Here is the link](http://www.oxfordjournals.org/our_journals/nar/database/subcat/3/9).

Comment: This is definitely a good resource. It looks like most of the tools are very specific. I am hoping to find something more general; like string-db.org

Answer (score 1):

STRING is one available tool http://string-db.org/ and allowes you to do multiple sequences/names. I would also take an indepth look at what expasy has to offer http://www.expasy.org/proteomics. It is a large collection of bioinformatics tools (far too many for me to go through) and almost always has the tool you want.

(As a side note Expasy also has tools in genomics, structural bioinformatics, and many more, check the left hand tabs on the website for the full list!).